# Virtual host not working in zend framework

Tags: apache, zend-framework, virtualhost, ubuntu-11.04

Following is my virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/roomstays/public"

ServerName roomstays

#This should be omitted in the production environment
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

<Directory "/var/www/roomstays/public">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Also it enabled on /etc/apache2/sites-enabled folder

And following is my host file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   roomstays

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I configured my site in var/www/roomstays. But when I entered roomstays on it not opening the site and showing this message :

It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

What's wrong with virtual host.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since enabling the site?

Comment: @TimFountain : Yes...I restared apache everytime after changing

Comment: There where a couple of different options in the accepted answer, which one worked for you? Also, on which machine did you access the site successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things to check:

**1. Sites enabled**

Make sure your virtual host file is in /etc/apache2/sites-**enabled**.

**2. NameVirtualHost**

Make sure you have this somewhere in the apache config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

I have it in /etc/apache2/ports.conf (can't remember if thats the standard on Ubuntu)

**3. Remove default virtual host**

If none of the above works, you can rename your virtual host to something like /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000000-myhost. This will ensure your virtual host file is loaded first. Alternatively remove /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

Remember to restart apache after each change...

Answer (score 4):

How to set up virtual host for Zend Project:

Create project(folder) in location /var/www/  named 'roomstays'

Put in file   /etc/hosts  line:

```
127.0.0.1 roomstays.test
```

Create file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ named "roomstays.conf" and put in it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias roomstays.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/roomstays/public/
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /var/www/roomstays/public/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Copy that file 'roomstays.conf' to location /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

Restart apache, open browser and enter "roomstays.test" and that's work for me.

Comment: then the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

is it not conflicting with localhost? try assigning a different IP address like

```
127.0.0.2
```

and also make sure you have added a directory with the alias name in to the apache log files directory

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix this problem. Copy the virtualhost file in etc/apache2/sites-available and paste it into etc/apache2/sites-enabled. Go to your browser and refresh and you would see it work

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName overstock.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\overstock"
 <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\overstock">
    AllowOverride All
   </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

Then change htaccess to

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /overstock/

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that **# Virtual hosts** line is active in your **httpd.conf** file.

Generally, it places under: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

To edit the file you need root permission, so:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Uncomment the line

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Save file **ESC + :wq + Enter**

Restart your apache