# Download file using zenframework 3

Tags: php, download, controller, zend-framework3

I could not find an answer anywhere, not even here, so this is my question.

In this hello example this the controller to download the file:

```
class DownloadController extends AbstractActionController 
{
    /**
    * This is the default "index" action of the controller. It displays the 
    * Downloads page.
    */
    public function indexAction() 
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    /**
    * This is the 'file' action that is invoked
    * when a user wants to download the given file.     
    */
    public function fileAction() 
    {


        // Get the file name from GET variable
        $fileName = $this->params()->fromQuery('name', '');

        // Take some precautions to make file name secure
        $fileName = str_replace("/", "", $fileName);  // Remove slashes
        $fileName = str_replace("\\", "", $fileName); // Remove back-slashes

        // Try to open file
        $path = './data/download/' . $fileName;


        if (!is_readable($path)) {
            // Set 404 Not Found status code
            $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);            
            return;
        }

        // Get file size in bytes
        $fileSize = filesize($path);

        // Write HTTP headers
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $headers = $response->getHeaders();
        $headers->addHeaderLine(
                "Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        $headers->addHeaderLine(
                "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . 
                $fileName . "\"");
        $headers->addHeaderLine("Content-length: $fileSize");
        $headers->addHeaderLine("Cache-control: private"); 

        // Write file content        
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($path);
        if($fileContent!=false) {                
            $response->setContent($fileContent);
        } else {        
            // Set 500 Server Error status code
            $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(500);
            return;
        }

        // Return Response to avoid default view rendering
        return $this->getResponse();

    }
}
```

I get this error while running it in Apache2 web-server:

```
A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.
Controller:
Application\Controller\DownloadController 
No Exception available
```

But it works fine when using PHP built-in server:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8081 -t helloworld public/index.php
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should **return $response instead of $this->getResponse()**. 
I will show my working code for downloading file:

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    $file = 'file content...';

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $headers  = $response->getHeaders();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=filename.csv")
        ->addHeaderLine("Pragma: no-cache")
        ->addHeaderLine("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");

    $response->setContent($file);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it did not work. I get this error: C:\Users\user~1\AppData\Local\Temp\S7k+Cocu.txt.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

Try again later, or contact the server administrator.

Comment: I just uploaded the project to a cluod server  and it works without code modifications. The problem should be with the apache2 server configuration. May be an htaccess file?

Comment: Hm.. yea, it's probably apache mis configuration problem. Check my answer here how to configure ZF and apache vhost  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259874/949273 .htaccess should be default one from the installation..

Comment: thank you It is working I just aded "Order Allow,Deny"
and   "Allow From All" to the virtual conf file.

Comment: Did my link help you?